# What is a dialog context?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, dialogfragment

I have a class in which I have this:

```
public TrabalharFicheiro(Context context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

And I have a dialogfragment which has this:

```
public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.dialog_adicionar_produtos, 
        container, false);
    var test = new TrabalharFicheiro (this);

    return view;
}
```

It gives me an error:

> "Cannot convert from 'Activity1.dialog' to
> 'Android.Content.Context'(CS1503)"

What is the context I should put instead of `this`?

Comment: Could you post a bit more of surrounding code? Specifically preceding this line `var test = new TrabalharFicheiro (this);`.

Comment: I have already edited it

Comment: `this` in this line means an instance of `TrabalharFicheiro` class. I'm not completely sure there's analogue of the java method `getActivity()` in c# but perhaps there should be one: `var test = new TrabalharFicheiro (GetActivity());`

Comment: I tried that, but the xamarin doesnt recognise " GetActivity()"

Comment: try `var test = new TrabalharFicheiro (this.Activity);`

Comment: the context is working now, but when it initializes the dialog, it kiles the variables that I am passing to the activity

Comment: that's a different problem. What do you mean by "it kills variables"?

Comment: @Android777 go check my new question, It has to do with this.       Passing strings from an Activity to a DialogFragment

Comment: Just so it resolved. If you don't mind I'll post the answer to this question, so we can close the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in this line means an instance of `TrabalharFicheiro` class.

`var test = new TrabalharFicheiro (this.Activity);` should be used.